Will low power factor power supplies overload a circuit sooner?
The Meanwell LRS-350-12 is a 350W AD->DC power supply (specs here) that is really popular in the DIY LED Christmas light community in the US. But they have a very low power factor (about 0.55).
I'm trying to understand if using a high PF supply would allow me to run more of these supplies on a single circuit. Taking the PF into account gives an RMS input current of 6.5A per supply. Is RMS input current what one should be looking at for circuit capacity, meaning I could run only two at full load? Or is that not how it works?
With a high PF supply, RMS input current would fall to under 4A, which, if that is the number to look at, would be within spec for 3 supplies on a 15A circuit.

I believe your question can be summarized:  how many AC-to-DC power supplies could be run off a single 120V AC mains 15A branch circuit if the power supplies have a poor power-factor?  Your thinking is correct that Power Factor is part of the equation.  The wiring and the circuit breaker back in the distribution box are concerned with amount of current in the branch circuit, rather than actual power delivered.  The actual current in the wire is what causes the wire to heat up.
When power factor is low, then more current is used to deliver the same power compared to when the power factor is 1.  So the sum of the maximum actual currents (6.5A for each proposed supply per your calculations) should not exceed the ratings of the circuit breaker or the wires and extension cords.  A better power factor for the AC-DC supplies will reduce current flowing from the AC mains while delivering the same actual power, and you could possibly have more supplies per 15A branch circuit.

Oh, and if you have learned this much already, definitely you have earned the excuse to purchase some test instruments to verify behavior of real circuits.   An inexpensive power usage monitor such as the Kill-A-Watt meter (inserted in-line between outlet and load) would allow you to measure power factor and current drawn by AC load.  A basic clamp on AC meter will measure actual AC current anywhere the individual AC wires are exposed without disconnecting any wires (careful not to touch live wires!).   I have one of each ;)

Thanks so much for the helpful explanation. A Kill-A-Watt is on my list; I also have a clamp on meter along with a little outlet plug "adapter" that gives a place to clamp around the wires without having to expose anything... the clamp-on meter has been very useful, but I was not sure if the numbers it reported were the right ones to look at for determining how much circuit capacity I was using. Now I know. :-)

I've had good luck with Meanwell supplies at home and in the lab based on price/performance ratio, complete specifications, and so far reliable.   All datasheets have to summarize measurements, so sometimes hard to read between the lines to determine how device will perform in a specific application.  Just like efficiency, the PF can vary over delivered load current.  Best bet is to actually measure how this device performs in your application if you have concerns about making larger investment.

I don't see the power factor in the spec. 0.55 is extremely low -- is this correct for full load ?

Sorry. The spec sheet list a current usage of 6.8A for full load. It is a 348W power supply and specifies an efficiency of 85% at 115 VAC, and 348W/115VAC/0.85 efficiency = 3.56A if it has a perfect power factor (DC wattage divided by input current divided by efficiency). Then 3.56A/6.8A =  52% PF, if I did the math correctly.

It looks like you are focusing on the power factor for the power supply which isn't really something I'd be concerned about. The power factor isn't specified on the data sheet so I wouldn't be relying on calculations to determine it as with these electronics there could be more going on than you can work out with a simple rms calculation. Meanwell sells relatively cost effective power supplies so I would be expecting it would be much more cost effective for you to buy two or three meanwell power supplies rather than trying to find a high end one which has specific power factor characteristics.
Also if you are worried about efficiency you might want to look at a switchmode power supply as these are more electrically efficient than standard 24V power supplies.

You might want to look into the power supply in question to understand it is indeed a SMPS.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
